# How to read the div child elements of anchor tag values in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

How to read the div child elements of anchor tag values in javascript or jquery?

```html
<div id="generate-here">
   <div id="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a href="#">test</a></div>
   <div id="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a href="#">test123</a></div>
   <div id="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a href="#">abc</a></div>
</div>
```

I am tried this solution:

```js
var numberOfdivs = $('#generate-here').children('div').length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfdivs; i++) {
    $("#box").children("a").each(function() {
        mails += $(this).val() + ',';
    });
}
```

Comment: you mean `function deleteAt(lnk) { console.log(lnk.textContent) }` ???

Comment: noo. not on click, i am try to reading the every 'div' anchor tag value, i mention the my tried solution please check once

Comment: Hi, I am tried with below solution that's why I didn't accept the your solution.i am sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `querySelectorAll`:

```js
const q = document.querySelectorAll("div a")

const res = [...q].map(el => el.getAttribute("href"))

console.log(res)
```

```html
<div id="generate-here">

  <div id="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a onclick="deleteAt(this)" href="#">test</a>
  </div>
  <div id="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a onclick="deleteAt(this)" href="#ffff">test123</a>
  </div>
  <div id="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a onclick="deleteAt(this)" href="#">abc</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique

anchors have textContent or href

To get all link texts you can do

```js
const mails = [...document.querySelectorAll("#generate-here .box a")]
  .map(lnk => lnk.textContent); // Array .map - change to lnk.href for URLs
console.log(mails.join(", "))
```

```html
<div id="generate-here">
  <div class="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a href="#">test</a></div>
  <div class="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a href="#">test123</a></div>
  <div class="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a href="#">abc</a></div>
</div>
```

Use

```
.map(lnk => { 
  const { textContent, href } = lnk; 
  return ({ [textContent]: href })
})
```

if you want both text and href

jQuery

```js
const mails = $("#generate-here .box a")
  .map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get(); // jQuery map
console.log(mails.join(", "))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="generate-here">
  <div class="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a href="#">test</a></div>
  <div class="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a href="#">test123</a></div>
  <div class="box" style="padding-left:5px;"><a href="#">abc</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tqs, it wokrks fine.